# how to see the full path of files or folders in CHKDSK?

Tags: windows, command-line, chkdsk

is there a way to see full paths when using CHKDSK instead of just file names and folder names?

context: this way i know exactly what to restore from my backups

Comment: what does chkdsk have to do with backups?

Comment: Do you mean the Command Prompt?

Comment: @Moab yes i mean the command prompt. if chkdsk mentions a file then it usually means there is something wrong with such a file. i was just providing some context about why i want the full path

Comment: I would look in event viewer, it will log when the chkdsk when it completes, there may be more information in there.

Comment: @Moab i already looked there. event viewer seems to contain exact same text that was output in the command prompt. it even cuts off at some point

Comment: I don/t think it is possible to get full path when using chkdsk.